# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env: Failed anonymous mmap: Permission denied. See process maps in the log

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, hilos, android-room

Estaba desarrrollando una App en Android con java, en la que conecto con una BBDD local impletada con Room, en la que intento recuperar una serie de url de imagenes para pintarlas despus en un ImageView en el Fragment.

Mi problema viene que al intentar hacer la consulta y meterla en un hilo a parte, me daba un error en el que me decia que los componentes de la UI, solo los podía controlar el MainThread, asi que lo implemente de la siguinete manera:

JournalFragment.fragment

```
package com.example.journal.ui.journal;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.journal.Login;
import com.example.journal.R;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.BirdRoom;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.Birddb;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.journal.R.id.item_imgDiario;


public class JournalFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recycleView;
    private JournalViewModel mViewModel;
    private TextView txtTitulo, txtHora;
    private ImageView itemJornal;
    private List<BirdRoom> birds;
    public static JournalFragment newInstance() {
        return new JournalFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        itemJornal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imgDiario);
        txtTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTituloDiario);
        txtHora = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtHora);
        // RECOVER THE DATA FROM THE CAPTURE FRAGMENT.
        //TODO: Creo que lo que recupere el Jornal debeía ser desde la BBDD local de Room, ya que desde un Bundle siempre va a llegar Null.
        //TODO: Crear uno hilo para hacer la consulta a la BBDD.

        //Set the hour.
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hora, minutos, segundos,dia, mes, annio;
        String mes_string;
        hora =calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2;
        minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        segundos = calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DATE);
        annio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        switch (mes){
            case 1:
                mes_string = "ENERO";
                break;
            case 2:
                mes_string = "FEBRERO";
                break;
            case 3:
                mes_string = "MARZO";
                break;
            case 4:
                mes_string = "ABRIL";
                break;
            case 5:
                mes_string = "MAYO";
                break;
            case 6:
                mes_string = "JUNIO";
                break;
            case 7:
                mes_string = "JULIO";
                break;
            case 8:
                mes_string = "AGOSTO";
                break;
            case 9:
                mes_string = "SEPTIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 10:
                mes_string = "OCTUBRE";
                break;
            case 11:
                mes_string = "NOVIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 12:
                mes_string = "DICIEMBRE";
                break;
            default:
                mes_string = "";
        }

        txtHora.setText(hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos + " - " + dia + " " + mes_string + " " +  annio);
        itemJornal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(item_imgDiario);
        //itemJornal.setImageDrawable(null);

        /*
                //TODO: PROBAR A INSERTAR UNA INSTANCIA DE BIRDROOM EN LA BBDD PARA VER SI ES PORQUE NO TIENE DATOS.

         */
       AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //TODO: SE QUEDA LA UI COLGADA PORUQE PETA EL MAIN-THREAD

                //Set the Looper for the Toast.
                if(Looper.getMainLooper()==null){
                    Looper.prepareMainLooper();
                }
                requestBirds(view);
            }
        });
    }

    private void requestBirds(View view) {

        //Recover the data from Room bbdd.
        Birddb bd = Birddb.getDatabase(getContext());
        birds = Arrays.asList(bd.birdDAO().loadAllBirds());

        //TODO: Cargar el recycleView en otro hilo, que no se el MainThread.

        setUpRecycleView(view);

    }

    private void setUpRecycleView(View view) {


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                updateUi(view);
            }
        }, view);



    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable, View view) {


            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i++ < 1000) {
                        try {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateUi(view);
                                }
                            }, view);
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

    private void updateUi(View view) {

        //TODO: SOlucionar UI bloqueda al hacer la Consulta a la BBDD.

        if(!birds.isEmpty()){
            //TODO: Cargar con un for, las descripciones con los ImageView a partir de la Url de la imagen.
            //TODO: Solucionar error con RecycleView.

            recycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
            recycleView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewAdapter(birds, getContext()));

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se dispone de ninguna foto actualmente en su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

y el error que vierte es este:

```
2021-04-26 13:36:26.285 22485-23353/com.example.journal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-713
    Process: com.example.journal, PID: 22485
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env: Failed anonymous mmap(0x0, 8192, 0x3, 0x22, -1, 0): Permission denied. See process maps in the log.
        at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:883)
        at com.example.journal.ui.journal.JournalFragment.runOnUiThread(JournalFragment.java:195)
        at com.example.journal.ui.journal.JournalFragment.access$200(JournalFragment.java:45)
        at com.example.journal.ui.journal.JournalFragment$3.run(JournalFragment.java:182)
```

Comment: No dupliques preguntas. Si quieres añadir o modificar información de tu pregunta anterior, edítala.

Comment: Perdonar, ha sido un error no queria publicarla dos veces. Ya he eliminado la otra.

Comment: Podrías decirme qué hace este método? `private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable, View view)` ?? Porque este loop: `while (i++ < 1000) {try {runOnUiThread(` está causando una recursividad curiosa... cada vez que llamas al método, llamas 1000 veces más ese método, y cada una de esas llamadas, llamará 1000 veces más ese método, con lo cual en la segunda vuelta del loop ya tienes 1 millón de llamadas, además de 1 millón de threads!.... si llegase al final tendrías 1000 * 1000 * 1000, para hacer qué??

Comment: Si lo que pretendes es mantener los datos actualizados, lo suyo es usar un observer, listener o un viewmodel con javarx por ejemplo para que se actualice cuando detecta un cambio... no mil millones de threads setteando cada uno un adapter de nuevo!

Comment: Igual son muchos Threads... si es verdad... En cuanto a lo de la implementacion dado que us fragments creo que lo mejor seria implmentar el ViewModel, no??